# Prime reciprocal sum

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

\begin{align}
&f(k)=
\begin{cases}
1/k\text{ if $k$ is prime}\\
0\text{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\\
\\
&\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\sim\log\log n+M
\end{align}

where $M$ is the Meissel–Mertens constant, seems far closer to the truth than $$\sum_{{k=1}}^{n}1/p_k\sim\log\log n+M$$

Is this the case?

[image]

The plot is of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$ (blue )$\log\log n+M$ (red). This is different to [this plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant#mediaviewer/File:Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant_definition.svg)

Compare:

```
singleNumPa[om_, number_] := 
If[number == 1, 0, If[PrimeOmega[number] < om, 1, 0]]/number
Show[Accumulate[singleNumPa[2, #] & /@ Range@1000] // ListLinePlot, 
Plot[Log@Log[x] + .2614972128476427837554268386086958590516, {x, 2, 
1000}, PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
Show[Accumulate[1/Prime[#] & /@ Range@1000] // ListLinePlot, 
ListLinePlot[
Table[(Log@Log[x] + .2614972128476427837554268386086958590516), {x, 
1, 1000}], PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
```

## Update

Apologies to all - misread Wiki article as prime reciprocals as opposed to $p<n$

Comment: The two expressions you have posted are equal, assuming by summing over $\mathbb{P}$ you mean over primes $\leq n$.

Comment: You mean $\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=\log\log n+M$ for the first thing. What do you even mean by the second?

Comment: @nullUsernot really, since summing lots of zeros slows the sum.

Comment: I mean $\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) = \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^N 1/p$

Comment: @martin Based on your comment, should your second thing be $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/p_k$?

Comment: @whacka yes, probably - will alter

Comment: After correctly interpreting what you're trying to convey: The reason the first thing seems closer than the second is because the first is true and the second is false. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Okay, now you're saying the plots are indistinguishable, contradicting the fact that the two sums I'm talking about are definitely distinguishable (unless you just programmed one of the graphs wrong), and then you seem to contradict yourself again by saying [something?] is "very different from the second." Just tell us once and for all, what in the world are you talking about? Be as clear and precise as you can possibly be.

Comment: @whacka the plot is of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)$ (blue )$\log\log n+M$ (red). This is different to [this plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant#mediaviewer/File:Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant_definition.svg)

Comment: Oh okay, your graph plots both sides of the first asymptotic, it doesn't compare the first sum with the second sum. My bad. Please *say* that though. The only reason your graph is different from the one you just linked to is because you added the $+M$ to the $\log\log n$, shifting the bottom one up to meet the top one.

Comment: You said your plot compares $\sum_{p\le n}1/p$ with $\log\log n+M$, and Wikipedia's plot compares $\sum_{p\le n}1/p$ with $\log\log n$ and shows there is a gap of $M$. Right?

Comment: @whacka yes, you are right - misread Wiki entry as primes reciprocals, as opposed to $p<n$ :(

Comment: One key difference is that the wikipedia graph uses a log scale for the horizontal ($n$) axis, which accentuates what's going on for small values of $n$.

Comment: @BarryCipra yes - silly mistake - apologies for time wasting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your first sum $S_1(n)$ and the second $S_2(n)$.  Since $p_n\approx n\ln n$, then we have $S_2(n)\approx S_1(n\ln n)$, or alternately $S_1(n)\approx S_2(\frac n{\ln n})$.  But $\ln(\ln(\frac{n}{\ln n}))$ $= \ln(\ln n-\ln\ln n)$ $= \ln(\ln n\cdot(1-\frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n}))$ $=\ln\ln n+\ln(1-\frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n})$ $\approx \ln\ln n-\frac{\ln \ln n}{\ln n}$ — and note that I haven't tried to roll any specific constants in here.  The latter value is small and tends to zero as $n\to\infty$, so asymptotically there's no difference between the two expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Using the estimate $\pi(n)=\frac{n}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)^2}\right)$, your sum can also be written as
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\pi(k)-\pi(k-1)}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\pi(k)}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\pi(k)}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\pi(k)}{k(k+1)}+\frac{\pi(n)}{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\frac{k}{\log(k)}+O\left(\frac{k}{\log(k)^2}\right)}{k(k+1)}+\frac{\pi(n)}{n+1}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{(k+1)\log(k)}+O(1)\\[12pt]
&=\log(\log(n))+O(1)
\end{align}
$$
However
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}\frac1{p_k}\\
\end{align}
$$
So the difference
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{p_k}-\sum_{k=2}^nf(k)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{p_k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}\frac1{p_k}\\
&=\sum_{k=\pi(n)+1}^n\frac1{p_k}\\
&=\sum_{k=\pi(n)+1}^n\frac1{k\log(k)+O(k)}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{k=\pi(n)+1}^n\frac1{k\log(k)}+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\log(\log(n))-\log(\log(n/\log(n)))+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)\\[12pt]
&=\log(\log(n))-\log(\log(n)-\log(\log(n)))+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)\\[9pt]
&\to0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the [Meissel-Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) will be the same either way.