# Simplest proof that $\sum 1/p$ grows like $\log \log x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am seeking recommendations for a **simple** proof that $\sum_{p<x} 1/p$ grows like $\log (\log (x))$.

By **simple** I mean suitable for secondary school or 1st year university students - not those who are already trained in mathematics.

Ideally the proof would start from Euler's product formula for the Riemann zeta function, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Proof_that_the_series_exhibits_log-log_growth ?

Comment: Related: [Prime reciprocal sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156896/prime-reciprocal-sum)

Comment: Presumably Landau's old textbook has an elementary proof, which may not be simple.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff - we've found that for other questions many of the "elementary" proofs end up being more complicated and the complex proofs much simpler.

Comment: @BarryCipra I have looked at wikipedia but was hoping for a simpler clearer proof. The one on wiki is probably the one we'll go with in the absence of other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the knowledge of partial summation, we just use the traditional summation by parts:

Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $x$, so for all $n\in\mathbb Z^{>0}$

$$
\pi(n)-\pi(n-1)=
\begin{cases}
1 & n\text{ is prime} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Applying this to our problem, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{p\le N}\frac1p
&=\sum_{n=1}^N{\pi(n)-\pi(n-1)\over n}={\pi(N)\over N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\pi(n)\over n}-\sum_{n=1}^N{\pi(n-1)\over n} \\
&={\pi(N)\over N}+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}{\pi(n)\over n}-\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}{\pi(n)\over n+1}={\pi(N)\over N}-\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\pi(n)\left[{1\over n+1}-\frac1n\right] \\
&={\pi(N)\over N}+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\pi(n)\int_n^{n+1}{\mathrm dt\over t^2}={\pi(N)\over N}+\int_2^N{\pi(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $N=\lfloor x\rfloor$, then

$$
\int_N^x{\pi(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt=\pi(N)\int_N^x{\mathrm dt\over t^2}={\pi(N)\over N}-{\pi(x)\over x}
$$

As a result, the above formula applies to all $x\in\mathbb R_{>0}$:

$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p={\pi(x)\over x}+\int_2^x{\pi(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt
$$

By the prime number theorem, we know that there exists a positive constant $K$ such that

$$
\left|\pi(x)-{x\over\log x}\right|\le{Kx\over\log^2x}
$$

As a result, using big O notation, the above thing becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p
&={1\over\log x}+\int_2^x{\mathrm dt\over t\log t}+\int_2^x\mathcal O\left(1\over t\log^2t\right)\mathrm dt+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log^2 x\right) \\
&=\log\log x+\mathcal O(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

That we can immediately conclude the error term is of $\mathcal O(1)$ is mainly because it is evident that the other terms would not exceed some constant.

P.S. Indeed a stronger result Mertens' theorem which states

$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p=\log\log x+B_1+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log x\right)
$$

can be proven using elementary methods without prime number theorem, but it will require more technical details.

Comment: See my answer, the elementary approach is not hard

Comment: @reuns Well, if you assume the OP knows Chebyshev's estimates and Mertens' theorems, the approach is indeed easy

Comment: @TravorLZH thanks this is really very helpful. The only small bump might be the step. that uses the PNT which is an unfamiliar form to the more commonly $\pi(x) \sim x/\ln(x)$. The form you use which suggests the error is $\leq \frac{Kx}{\log^2t}$ is not familiar to me - could you provide a link to where I can find out more about this?

Comment: It's oftentimes called the PNT with remainder. In 1896, de la Vallee Poussin showed that $\pi(x)=\operatorname{Li}(x)+\mathcal O(xe^{-\sqrt{c\log x}}) $ for some positive constant $c$, and because $\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\mathrm dt/\log t=x/\log x+\mathcal O(x/\log^2x)$ and $xe^{-\sqrt{c\log x}}\ll x/\log^2x$, we obtain $\pi(x)=x/\log x+\mathcal O(x/\log^2x)$

Comment: @TariqRashid For a link, see [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html)

Answer (score 3):

$$(1+O(\frac1{\log n}))n\log n = \log n! = \sum_{p^k \le n} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor\log p $$ $$= (1+O(\frac1{\log n}))\sum_{p \le n} n \frac{\log p}{p}\tag{1}$$
Followed by a partial summation
$$\sum_{p\le n} \frac1p = \frac{\sum_{p\le n} \frac{\log p}p}{\log n}+\sum_{m \le n-1} (\sum_{p\le m} \frac{\log p}p) (\frac1{\log m}-\frac1{\log (m+1)})$$
$$ =  \frac{(1+O(\frac1{\log n}))\log n}{\log n}+\sum_{m\le n-1}(1+O(\frac1{\log m})) \log m  \frac{1+O(\frac1{m})}{m\log^2 m}$$ $$=\log \log n+C+O(\frac1{\log n})$$

Comment: In $(1)$ I am using that $\sum_{p\le n} \log p = O(n)$ which follows from $\sum_{p\in (n,2n]} \log p \le \log {2n\choose n}= O(n)$